# How to toggle (hide / show) sidebar div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have 2 `<div>`s with ids `A` and `B`. div `A` has a fixed width, which is taken as a sidebar.

The layout looks like diagram below:

[image: Layout]

The styling is like below:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#A, #B {
    position: absolute;
}
#A {
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#B {
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

I have `<a id="toggle">toggle</a>` which acts as a toggle button. On the toggle button click, the sidebar may hide to the left and div `B` should stretch to fill the empty space. On second click, the sidebar may reappear to the previous position and div `B` should shrink back to the previous width.

How can I get this done using jQuery?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$('button').toggle(
function() {
    $('#B').css('left', '0')
}, function() {
    $('#B').css('left', '200px')
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/1/

You can also see any animated version at http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/2/

Comment: toggle was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9

Comment: toggle is _still_ in jQuery, but the signature is not as this answer demonstrates. [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Hi, why does on jQuery yields to showing/hiding of button see http://jsfiddle.net/7pf044cn/

Answer (score 12):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FMZY/) for a preview and check the documentation for [jquerys toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) methods.

```
$('#toggle').toggle(function(){
    $('#A').animate({width:0});
    $('#B').animate({left:0});
},function(){
    $('#A').animate({width:200});
    $('#B').animate({left:200});
});
```

Basically you animate on the properties that sets the layout.

A more advanced version:

```
$('#toggle').toggle(function(){
    $('#A').stop(true).animate({width:0});
    $('#B').stop(true).animate({left:0});
},function(){
    $('#A').stop(true).animate({width:200});
    $('#B').stop(true).animate({left:200});
})
```

This stops the previous animation, clears animation queue and begins the new animation.

Answer (score 5):

You can visit w3school for the solution on this the link is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push_opacity) and there is another example also available that might surely help,
[Take a look](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp)

Answer (score 2):

The following will work with new versions of jQuery.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){

    var toggle = false;

    $('button').click(function() {
        toggle = !toggle;

        if(toggle){
            $('#B').animate({left: 0});
        }
        else{
            $('#B').animate({left: 200});
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Javascript**

```js
var side = document.querySelector("#side");
var main = document.querySelector("#main");
var togg = document.querySelector("#toogle");
var width = window.innerWidth;

window.document.addEventListener("click", function() {

  if (side.clientWidth == 0) {
//    alert(side.clientWidth);
    side.style.width      = "200px";
    main.style.marginLeft = "200px";
    main.style.width      = (width - 200) + "px";
    togg.innerHTML        = "Min";
  } else {
//    alert(side.clientWidth);
    side.style.width      = "0";
    main.style.marginLeft = "0";
    main.style.width      = width + "px";    
    togg.innerHTML        = "Max";
  }

}, false);
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative; 
  display: block; 
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.5s; 
}

#side {
  left: 0;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}
 
#main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;    
}
```

```html
<button id="toogle">Max</button>
<div id="side">Sidebar</div>
<div id="main">Main</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('#B').toggleClass('extended-panel');
  $('#A').toggle(/** specify a time here for an animation */);
});
```

and in the CSS:

```
.extended-panel {
  left: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".trigger").click(function () {
        $("#sidebar").toggle("fast");
        $("#sidebar").toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});


<div>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
        <img id="icon-menu" alt='menu' height='50' src="Images/Push Pin.png" width='50' />
    </a>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
```

Instead #sidebar give the id of ur div.

Answer (score -1):

This help to hide and show the sidebar, and the content take place of the empty space left by the sidebar.

```
<div id="A">Sidebar</div>
<div id="B"><button>toggle</button>
Content here: Bla, bla, bla
</div>


//Toggle Hide/Show sidebar slowy
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#B').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('#A').toggle('slow');
          $('#B').toggleClass('extended-panel'); 
      });
  }); 


html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#A, #B {
    position: absolute;
}
#A {
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background:orange;
}
#B {
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    background:green;
}

/* makes the content take place of the SIDEBAR 
   which is empty when is hided */
.extended-panel {
  left: 0px !important;
}
```