# How to toggle sidebar div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have the exact same question as this one:
[How to toggle (hide / show) sidebar div using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576893/how-to-toggle-hide-show-sidebar-div-using-jquery)

Unfortunately this doesn't work anymore with jQuery 1.9.1.
How do I get the same result with the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: If you are talking about the method toggle, then it's ok to use. If you are talking about the toggle event, it's deprecated/removed http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
(function() {
    var state = 0;
    var toggle = function() {
        if (state === 0) {
            $('#B').css('left', '0');
            state = 1;
        } else {
            $('#B').css('left', '200px');
            state = 0;
        }
    }

    $('button').click(toggle);
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$('button').click(function(){
     $('#My_div_id').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Although jQuery [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/),[slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) and [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) are the most common tools for the job, using [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) adds a bit more flexibility since you can set your style/animation in CSS and separate it  from your JS code.
e.g.

```
.item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s;
    -ms-transition: width 1s;
    -o-transition: width 1s;
    transition: width 1s;
}
.item.hidden {
    width: 0;
}
```

and then:

```
$('.item').toggleClass('hidden');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/9y3Wq/)

Answer (score 0):

Make id selector for that element and than, id for element that is 'processor' for action.

For example:

```
$('#id1').click(function(){
$('#id2').slideToggle(x);
});
```

Where, x is number (1000) for one second. It also can be word, slow, fast.