# How to push the existing DOM element when a new element is created dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a DOM element (say div), I am created a new element using javascript (specifically react), The new element is another div which is a sidebar.
The desired implementation is when the sidebar enters, the previous element shifts and the sidebar does not overlay

Comment: sounds like something that can be done with css using transform translate property

Comment: Can you provide example(s) of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? Where the elements will move over based on the divs they are placed in?

```
$('button').toggle(
function() {
    $('#B').css('left', '0')
}, function() {
    $('#B').css('left', '200px')
})
```

Working example at:http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/1/

Credit to:[How to toggle (hide / show) sidebar div using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576893/how-to-toggle-hide-show-sidebar-div-using-jquery)