# How to make a generic toggle function in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-core, razor

I have a sidemenu in HTML like this:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<div class="col nav-left h-100">
<p>Menu</p>
</div>
```

In my **Site.js** I have made a generic JQuery function for the toggle:

```
var eventHandler = {
    addToggle: function addToggle(btnElem, openEvent, closeEvent) {
        const isClosedClass = 'this-is-closed';
        btnElem.click(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass(isClosedClass)) {
                openEvent();
            } else {
                closeEvent();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

In my **_Layout.cshtml** I call this function like this:

```
 <script>
        eventHandler.addToggle($(".btn-toggle-something"),
            function () {
                // Slide down
            },
            function () {
                // Slide up
            });

 </script>
```

Now I getting stuck how to write the logic for the actual toggle on a div.

How can I toggle my side menu with a generic function?

Sources I looked:

https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

[How to toggle (hide / show) sidebar div using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576893/how-to-toggle-hide-show-sidebar-div-using-jquery)

Comment: Have you tried `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`?

Comment: Do you have an example to achieve this?

Comment: How's this? https://jsfiddle.net/0ubhkfLq/6/

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking! Can you post your code in the answers so I can accept it?

Comment: Will do, one sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.slideUp()](https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [.slideDown()](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) in combination with [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) will work - please see below:

```js
var eventHandler = {
    addToggle: function addToggle(btnElem, openEvent, closeEvent) {
        const isClosedClass = 'this-is-closed';
        btnElem.click(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass(isClosedClass)) {
                openEvent();
            } else {
                closeEvent();
            }

            // Toggle `isClosedClass` for next time this is clicked.
            btnElem.toggleClass(isClosedClass);
        });
    }
};

// Bind slideDown/slideUp.
var leftNav = $('.nav-left');

eventHandler.addToggle($('.btn-toggle-something'),
    function () {
        leftNav.slideDown();
    },
    function () {
        leftNav.slideUp();
    }
);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-left {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}

.btn-toggle-something {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col nav-left h-100">
  <p>Menu</p>
</div>

<div class="btn-toggle-something">Toggle</div>
```